# How Can I get a query result from multiple model in Laravel 7?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two models **Scholarship** and **Level**, and they have **many to many relationship**. 
And for this I have two tables on my database as scholarships and levels, and a **pivot table level_scholarship**. I want to make a query for getting my scholarships based on scholarship (title, app_deadline) and level (name)

**Columns:**

My levels table have:  id, name, slug, created_at, updated_at

My scholarships table have: id, title, slug, description, image, university, app_deadline, deadline, remarks, place_id, created_at, updated_at

And level_scholarship have: id, scholarship_id, level_id, created_at, updated_at

**My Scholarship Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Scholarship extends Model
  {

      public function levels(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Level')->withTimestamps();
      }

}
```

**My Level Model**

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Level extends Model
     {
        public function scholarships(){
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Scholarship')->withTimestamps();
     }
  }
```

I can make query for Scholarship model, but how do I relate Level Model

```
 $query = $request->input('query');

    $field = Field::where('title','LIKE',"%$query%")->first();
    $fieldId = $field->id;

    $scholarships = $field->scholarships()->latest()->paginate(10);;

    $scholarship = Scholarship::where('title','LIKE',"%$query%")
        ->orWhere('app_deadline','LIKE',"%$query%")
        ->orWhere(scholarship()->levels()->name,'LIKE',"%$query%")
        ->latest()->get();
```

Comment: You can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and [querying relationship existance](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 $query = $request->input('query');
 $field = Field::where('title','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')->first();
 $fieldId = $field->id;
 $scholarships = $field->scholarships()->latest()->paginate(10);

 $scholarship = Scholarship::whereHas('levels' , function($q) use($query) {
      $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%');
 })
 ->where('title','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')
 ->orWhere('app_deadline','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')
 ->latest()->get();
```

Try This It will help You:

Edit 1:

```
$query = $request->input('query');
 $field = Field::where('title','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')->first();
 $fieldId = $field->id;
 $scholarships = $field->scholarships()->latest()->paginate(10);

 $scholarship = Scholarship::with(['levels' , function($q) use($query) {
      $q->where('name','LIKE','%' . $query. '%');
 }])
 ->where('title','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')
 ->orWhere('app_deadline','LIKE','%' . $query. '%')
 ->latest()->get();
```

Comment: no erro but i am not getting the outputs as expected: you can check it http://soar.shasthokontho.com

Comment: this is like your try i just modified !! tell me what you need?

Comment: i want to get my search result by title, deadline from scholarship table and by level name also and level are on level table

Comment: It shuld work unless any other error!! btw try the Edit 1

Comment: check the `like` query

Comment: whereHas('levels' , function($q) use($query) {
      $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%');
 })   this query not working at all